# Complex animations in Android (transitions, backgrounds...)

Tags: android, animation

I have in mind one simple application, but I would like to add some animations, transitions and so on. What technologies should I use besides **Android SDK**?

Concrete **example**: I have an **activity** with an **animated background** in constant loop (some waves, fancy shadows and graphics - maybe do it in Flash and import is or...?) and I have a big TextView in front. When user taps on screen - text **explodes** or **burns** or something like that and new text **reappear**. If I click on some button it also provides some **fancy animation**.

Should I use **AndEngine** or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use libgdx: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/

It has a bit of a learning curve, but its really flexibel